Uniqueness of Ahlfors dimension $Q$ in the definition of Ahlfors regularity, and the way to obtain it from the measure $\mu$
I just came across this definition of Ahlfors regularity of a measure $\mu$ and its Ahlfors dimension:


My questions are:

In the above definition, is $Q=0$ allowed, since that'd imply that the points (centers of the ball $B$'s) will get positive measure $\ge c?$

Is the Ahlfors dimension $Q$ uniquely determined by the measure? And if yes, is there a way to get back $Q$ from the measure? Is yes, how? For me, I was thinking along the following lines. So the definition above implies that:


$$0 < c \le \lim inf_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^Q} \le \lim  sup_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^Q} \le C < \infty.$$
So to get $Q$ from the measure, one can first calculate, for various  $R, \lim inf_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^R} ,  \lim sup_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^R},$ and the unique $R$ that'll make these two positive and finite, will be the Ahlfors dimension $Q.$ And this particular $R$ has to be unique, since
$$ 0 < \lim inf_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^Q} < \infty \implies \forall Q'> Q,  \lim inf_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^{Q'}} =\infty,$$
and
$$ 0 \le \lim sup_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^Q} < \infty \implies \forall Q' <Q,  \lim sup_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^{Q'}} = 0,$$
So this means $Q$ is uniquely determined by $\mu$ and can be defined directly from $\mu$ by:
$$Q:=\{R: 0 < c \le \lim inf_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^Q} \le \lim  sup_{r\to 0}\frac{B(a;r)}{r^Q} \le C < \infty \}.$$
Then the above argument shows that the above set, when non-empty, is singleton. So this uniquely determines $Q.$
Is my proof correct? If not, how do we show that $Q$ is unique and how do we construct it from $\mu?$
